# Shortcut for show / hide terminal?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

Switching over from mac os (iterm2) to elementary os.
One thing I am missing so far is the iterm2 shortcut which shows / hides the same instance of the terminal.
I know the super+T shortcut in eOS, but thats not what I am looking for.

How to achieve that? Do I need another terminal app for that?

Comment: You may ask elementary OS devs to implement this as a new feature (https://github.com/elementary/terminal/issues), and see what happens :)

Answer (score 1):

You can install `Guake` or `Yakuake`. These are the drop down terminals which will give you iterm2 like experience. 
To install `Guake` follow https://vitux.com/install-and-use-guake-a-drop-down-terminal-emulator-for-ubuntu/

Comment: also Tilix has this feature, I use it a lot for work

Answer (score 0):

You can use drop-down terminal like Tilda. It can be installed from app center.

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information, maybe add installation process. Have a nice day!

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the reminder.